# SSRS: Sorting on Lookup field Column within a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm having one field in my table as:

```
=LookUp(Fields!student_id.Value,Fields!student_id.Value,Fields!total_marks.Value, "Marks")
```

When I'm trying to sort the column based on  below expression, not having any sorted output:

```
=LookUp(Fields!student_id.Value,Fields!student_id.Value,Fields!total_marks.Value, "Marks")
```

Comment: Do you have any other sorting set that may be overriding?  On a group perhaps?

Comment: No, We are not having any other sorting. 
I tried to retrieve the Marks by means of custom code "Code.GetMarks(Fields!student_id.Value)" then too unable to sort.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your table design, including your sorting config?